# What does oobe\audit.exe do?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I ran `C:\Windows\System32\oobe\audit.exe` (bad idea, I know), I got a pop-up message saying "Windows could not complete the installation. To install Windows on this computer, restart the installation" and my computer immediately restarted after pressing OK. Now my computer has a defaultuser0 account, and my start menu and recent items have been cleared out. There may be other effects I haven't found yet. What exactly does this `audit.exe` do to my computer?

Comment: Here's a very nice answer at the HP Forums: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Audit-exe/td-p/5859391

Comment: @MichaelBay - The suggested answer would not help the author reverse the changes to his system.  All that answer explains is how to change the password policy on a password.  Enabling Audit mode does a great deal more then change the password policy on an account.

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly does this audit.exe do to my computer?

It is used to make changes to your current installation so a custom installation images can be created.

> Audit mode is used by OEMs and IT professionals to add customizations
>   to their Standard 7 images. Audit mode does not require settings in
>   Windows Welcome to be applied. By bypassing Windows Welcome, you can
>   access the desktop quicker and perform your customizations. You can
>   add more device drivers, install applications, and test the validity
>   of the installation. OEMs and corporations should use audit mode to
>   complete their manual customizations before shipping the computer to
>   an end-user.
>
> In audit mode, settings in an unattended answer file in the
>   auditSystem and auditUser configuration passes are processed. For more
>   information about these configuration passes, see auditSystem and
>   auditUser.

[Differences between Audit Mode and Windows Welcome (Standard 7 SP1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff794608(v=winembedded.60).aspx)

Comment: I suggest booting to a boot configuration from before you ran this particular executable.